# Strange behavior with c_str()

Tags: c++

When working with posix sockets how come

```
 write(new_socket, method.c_str(), sizeof(method.c_str()));
```

works but

```
write(new_socket, method.c_str(), method.length());
```

and

```
write(new_socket, method.c_str(), method.size());
```

do not work?

method is a 4 character string.

`sizeof(method.c_str())` returns 8.

`method.length()` returns 4.

`method.size()` returns 4.

`strlen(method_c_str())` returns 4.

Comment: `sizeof(method.c_str())` doesn't do what you think it does. It always will yield the size of a `char*` pointer, which usually is 8 at modern CPUs.

Comment: Define "works".

Comment: right, but write expects the length of string so why method.length() +1 or method.size()+1 or strlen(method.c_str()) +1 not work?

Comment: replys with empty

Comment: Who replies. What is "empty"?

Comment: this is for an http server. send a curl request to c++ server. then use write method to write back to curl client. curl outputs to console "curl (52) empty reply from server"

Comment: Have you checked the return of `write`?: _On success, the number of bytes written is returned (zero indicates nothing was written). On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately._

Comment: no error is returned

Comment: And whats the return value for `write(new_socket, method.c_str(), method.length());`?

Comment: the return value is 4

Comment: "method is a 4 character string", "the return value is 4" so it works as expected.

Comment: it looks like curl can only read strings at least 6 bytes in length

Comment: Mhm. Now thats bs. Since you haven't shown your code on the receiving side I can only guess, but I guess that you also want to send the terminating `'\0'`: `write(new_socket, method.c_str(), method.length() + 1);`

Comment: if method is 3 characters then `method.length() + 1` and `method.length() + 2` will not work but `method.length() + 3` will. Looks like it has to be at least 6 characters. My client code is just a command line curl request.

Comment: Postman doesnt even show the response at 8 bytes so it must be something with the way these http clients are handling responses

Comment: With everything bigger than `method.length() + 1` you'll have undefined behaviour. "My client code is just a command line curl request." Show it?

Comment: `curl -X POST 127.0.0.1:8080`

Answer (score -1):

The third argument of the function takes the number of bytes to be sent.
But size() and length() return the number of characters.
I think that you use a string of UTF-16 characters which need 2 byte per character. 
In this case it would be a possible solution to multiply the number of charaters(returned by size) by 2.

Comment: This is an English website, please post in English only.

Comment: Sorry, i think it was to early in the morning.

Comment: In this situation, the `method` variable is clearly a `std::string` and not a `std::wstring`, otherwise passing `c_str()` to `strlen()` would fail to compile (also because the OP is implementing an HTTP server, and HTTP uses 7bit ASCII strings). `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to always be 1 byte, so although `size()` and `length()` do return a *character* count, in the case of `std::string` they also represent a *byte* count.